# Completely Bypass shipping in Admin order entry

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

TL:DR  We need to bypass the shipping option while manually placing an order via the admin.  Currenly this isn't possible.

--

Ive had a request for manual order entry in the admin to be able to bypass shipping.  Its impossible to proceed without selecting *something*.

The issue at hand is that we only use USPS.  Randomly, we have a customer who can only accept FedEx.  Unfortunately the owners do not want to add FedEx or UPS to Magento, against my recommendation.

Their solution isn't elegant.  They've created a product that is just listed as 'FedEx Shipping' which they add to the order manually, then adjust its price to match what FedEx is charging.  It works, but at the bottom of the admin place order page its requiring a shipping method of what we currently offer.  We'd like to be able to bypass this, or have an option for 'No Shipping' or 'FedEx Shipping' (with no price?) so we can proceed to place the order.  However this 'no shipping' should only be visible in the admin.

Can I add a shipping bypass to the admin order page but only the admin order page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is a complex situation. As you already know, the best option is to do it using the FedEx setup.

I can think in two options for your case:

1. First option is to go in `Promotion > Shopping Cart Price Rules` and create a rule for free shipping using a specific coupon code. This way, just people with the coupon code would have free shipping and there is no risk to appear in your Frontend. [See more information here.](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-free-shipping.html)
2. Second option (and we do this in our company) is to have a Flat Rate shipping with price $ 0, and then name this something like "Pickup on store". This way you have the free shipping without creating logistic problems. Remember that this **will appear** in the Frontend. In order to do that, go to `System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods` and enable the option `Flat Rate`, put price equals 0 and name it (eg.: Pickup on Store).

Hope that can help, is the best "work around solution" that I was able to figure out :)